# Having a flash game that allows the user to choose a language

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a flash game (adobe animate and actionscript 3), and after the splash screen it should ask the user for a preferred language (choosing between two), and then it will take them to the home screen that's in the chosen language, and since I'm new to this field, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to implement it? any tips, please.

Comment: maybe you should do some research first.

Answer (score 2):

Create a localization data file (XML or JSON or CSV format, whichever is easy for you to work with). Develop your app so that **all** texts are obtained from that file via some kind of ids and none (not strictly, some initial texts like "Loading..." can still be in code) are hardcoded. When time is right, make a copy of localization file and translate the texts but leave the ids.

For example, en.xml:

```
<language>
    <entry id="game">Game</entry>
    <entry id="go">Go!</entry>
</language>
```

Then, ru.xml:

```
<language>
    <entry id="game">Игра</entry>
    <entry id="go">Вперёд!</entry>
</language>
```

The files have the same structure, same ids, everything, but the texts. When your app starts it should decide which one of the files is to load (or maybe load all of them and which one is to use), thus all the app texts will feature the appropriate language.